# Android Universal Image Loader slow, ignores ImageView height and width

Tags: android, image, gridview, universal-image-loader

I am using the Universal Image Loader library for a multiple image picker to display photos from phone's default gallery in a GridView, it displays all my images but really slow.

I have tried to follow their docs, and set everything to optimise for a quicker image display. At one point it suggests to set a fixed images size for my ImageView, I am doing so (110dp x 100dp) but it still loads slow and in the log I see that my images have a size of 220 x 240 dp. Why does it ignore my size settings?

To be clear, I would like to optimaize the UIL library with a fixed image size as it shows in the documentation, not to fit the images into my imageview.

image item inside gridview:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="1dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frmQueue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgQueue"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"

                android:src="@drawable/no_media" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgQueueMultiSelected"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:background="@drawable/on_focus_checkbox"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

settings of the library instance:

```
private void initImageLoader() {

    try {

        String CACHE_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/.temp_tmp";
        new File(CACHE_DIR).mkdirs();

        File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(getBaseContext(), CACHE_DIR);

        DisplayImageOptions defaultOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().cacheOnDisc(true).imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565).build();//.cacheInMemory(true)

        ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getBaseContext()).threadPoolSize(3).defaultDisplayImageOptions(defaultOptions).discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)).memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache());                  

        ImageLoaderConfiguration config = builder.build();
        imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
        imageLoader.init(config);
        //L.disableLogging();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitXY" add this property to your ImageView

Comment: @AnkitKumar this does not affect the way UIL resizes images.

Comment: I was facing same problem earlier, I solved it by this only .

Comment: @AnkitKumar - I have tried it, but it keeps saying in the log: 04-27 13:33:33.318: W/ImageLoader(31780): width = 220
04-27 13:33:33.318: W/ImageLoader(31780): height = 240

Comment: imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT).bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)    ... Try to remove from your defaultOptions

Comment: @AnkitKumar - no difference. :(

Comment: You should use `imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)` to get what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 private void initImageLoader() {
    DisplayImageOptions displayImageOptions = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.default_img)
            .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.default_img)
            .cacheOnDisk(true).build();

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
            .memoryCacheSize(20 * 1024 * 1024) // 20 Mb
            .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
            .diskCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(getCacheDir()))
            .diskCacheSize(20 * 1024 * 1024) //20 Mb
            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
                    //.enableLogging() // Not necessary in common
            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(displayImageOptions)
            .threadPoolSize(30)
            .build();

    com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);
}
```

This is my configuration, Please try to replicate it once. This is working fine for me.

Comment: Welcome :) @Edmond Tamas